# Javascript: Empty input with attribute required

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I created a form and as long as the inputs that have the **required attribute** are empty, the button will keep disabled.

When only the inputs with the required attribute are filled in, the button will be enabled.

How to do this with javascript?

```js
    // select all input with Attribute Required
    let elReq =
          document.querySelectorAll('input[required="required"]');

    // if elReq input is empty = .button disabled
    if (elReq.value == "") {
        document.querySelector('.button').disabled = true; 
        
    // if elReq input is filled in = .button enabled
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.button').disabled = false; 
    }
```

```css
      .button {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: .375rem .75rem;
            font-size: 1rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
      .button:disabled {
            color: #a2a5a9;
            border-color: #c9ced3;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            cursor: text;
        }
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form">
        <input type="number" id="a" class="a" placeholder="000" required>
        <input type="number" id="b" class="b" placeholder="0">

        <input type="number" id="c" class="c" placeholder="000" required>

        <input type="number" id="d" class="d" placeholder="000" required>
        
        <input type="number" id="e" class="e" placeholder="0">     
    </form>

        <button type="submit" value="Ok" id="send" class="button" onclick="sum()">Ok</button>
```

Basically, it's a common form. If the user doesn't fill in the mandatory fields, he won't be able to have access to the next step. For example, a login form: if the user doesn't fill the "e-mail" and the "password" inputs, the button "next" cannot be clicked. It's the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work.

Several weird things I think you should change.

1. You doesn't have the `eventListener`, so once the document load, it will check if the input has value or not (which always be `""`)
2. You have several things in the `input` has `required` attribute, so you have to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` and a loop to loop it

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[required]').forEach(item=>{
item.addEventListener('change',check)
window.addEventListener('load',check)
})

function check(){
for(let i of document.querySelectorAll('[required]')){
  if (!i.value) {
        document.querySelector('.button').disabled = true; 
        break;      
    } else {
    document.querySelector('.button').disabled = false;        
    }
}
}
```

```css
.button {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: .375rem .75rem;
            font-size: 1rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
      .button:disabled {
            color: #a2a5a9;
            border-color: #c9ced3;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            cursor: text;
        }
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form">
        <input type="number" id="a" class="a" placeholder="000" required>
        <input type="number" id="b" class="b" placeholder="0">

        <input type="number" id="c" class="c" placeholder="000" required>

        <input type="number" id="d" class="d" placeholder="000" required>
        
        <input type="number" id="e" class="e" placeholder="0">     
    </form>

        <button type="submit" value="Ok" id="send" class="button">Ok</button>
```

Comment: Hello James, unfortunately it didn't work. The button was enabled even with empty inputs. I did several tests, including querySelectorAll and other variations, but I didn't put them all here so as not to make the topic unnecessarily long. None of them worked. The code has a function sum() that should only be executed when the validated fields are filled. I don't understand how eventListener should fit in here (I'm learning javascript).

Comment: @Mari, I assume based on your code, you want to disable the button when all the input has value and keep the button enabled if a value is black (my code does work for this effect), the reason why you use eventListener is because you have to trigger the function to check if it has value. Otherwise, it will check all the begining  when window loaded. Now, I make the code to check the input value when you click the input button. Does this the thing you want?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but once I felt I was not clear, I edited the topic and tried to explain in other words.

Comment: @Mari, so you want to disable the button when there is a input blank?

Comment: Exactly this!......

Comment: @Mari, I just updated the code, check it now:)

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work :( The button is always blue (enable).

Comment: @Mari, are you sure? I check the code and test for several times. It will be disabled if there is one required input blank. **Note that you only have three required input**

Comment: My intention was that, as soon as we open the page, the button remain disabled.

Comment: @Mari, I try my best to guess what you really want. You want to make the form blank and when all three requird input has value, the button will immediately change to not disable? Is this correct?

Comment: I'm really sorry for not being clear and all the time you've trying to help me :( . But yes, as soon as the page is loaded, the button it's disable (gray color). Then, only after the user fill in the required input, the button will be enabled ready for the next step (blue).

Comment: @Mari, no problem. Just updated the code. Check it now!

Comment: It worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH (and I'm sorry!) :D